# How to sort a hash within a hash?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to sort a hash within a hash. I'd like to sort the hash by the sub-key. I'm using ruby.

I've tried using the sort_by method and iterating the over the hash to reorganize the sub-key. I received the error "ArgumentError: comparison of Hash with Hash failed"

```rb
hash = {2012 => {"regularseason" => [game_1, game_2, game_3],
                 "post_season" => [game_4, game_5] 
                 },
        2013 => {"regularseason" => [game_6, game_7, game_8],
                 "post_season" => [game_9, game_10] 
                 },
        2014 => {"post_season" => [game_11, game_12, game_13],
                 "regularseason" => [game_14, game_15] 
                 }
                 }
```

Desired Result:
I would like to sort this hash so sub-key post_season will always appear before sub-key regularseason.

Comment: Why are you trying to "sort a hash"? Ruby hashes, at least now, are "sorted" by insertion order. If you want something with arbitrary order, use something that's designed to preserve (or create) order. `sort_by` will let you sort by anything you want; if you want to create an array you'd need to feed it a function that sorts the *inner* hash. But presumably you *also* want to sort by year, so you're likely better off converting it to a more-appropriate structure.

Comment: As written, `game_1` (etc.) is a method or variable, whose value is unstated. It may be clearer to change them to literals (e.g., `:game_1` or `"game_1"`), as has been done in  the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Hash#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) to sort values:

```
hash.transform_values { |v| v.sort.to_h }
#⇒ {2012=>{"post_season"=>[:game_4, :game_5],
#          "regularseason"=>[:game_1, :game_2, :game_3]},
#   2013=>{"post_season"=>[:game_9, :game_10],
#          "regularseason"=>[:game_6, :game_7, :game_8]},
#   2014=>{"post_season"=>[:game_11, :game_12, :game_13],
#          "regularseason"=>[:game_14, :game_15]}}
```

Comment: thank you! this works :) If I wanted regularseason first, how would I do that?

Comment: Of course, it does. If you want some specific ordering, you’d need to use `#sort_by` and implement the sorter on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes return keys in the order they are inserted so I believe you'll essentially need to rewrite the nested hash.

For example:

```
hash.each { |(key, nested_hash)| hash[key] = nested_hash.sort.to_h }
```

This is rather inefficient, however, so you'd be better to see if you can ensure they are always entered in that order or somehow extract them in the order you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Given a hash with keys that include `k`, we can return a new hash with the same key/value pairs, with `k` being the first key inserted, and the remaining keys maintaining their original relative order, as follows:

```
def reorder_key(h, key)
  { key=>h[key] }.merge h
end
```

For example:

```
h = { 1=>2, :a=>:b, "c"=>"d" }
reorder_key(h, :a)
  #=> {:a=>:b, 1=>2, "c"=>"d"}
```

We can use this method to obtain the desired hash in the present problem.

```
hash.transform_values { |h| reorder_key(h, "post_season") }
  #=> {2012=>{"post_season"  =>[:game_4, :game_5], 
  #           "regularseason"=>[:game_1, :game_2, :game_3]},
  #    2013=>{"post_season"  =>[:game_9, :game_10],
  #           "regularseason"=>[:game_6, :game_7, :game_8]},
  #    2014=>{"post_season"  =>[:game_11, :game_12, :game_13],
  #           "regularseason"=>[:game_14, :game_15]}}
```

This approach does not depend on `"post_season"` coincidentally preceding `"regularseason"` lexicographically. If, for example, it were decided to add the key `"spring_training"` and make that the first key to appear for each year in the returned hash, it would only be necessary to change the value of the second argument of `reorder_key` to `"spring_training"`.